# Increase display window in figure

Tags: matplotlib, figure

I am using `matplotlib` to plot some histograms. As you can see in the image my figure is covered by the labels. 
 [image: my image]

I try the following:

```
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(10, 8), 
          dpi=180, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

But actually increase the whole window and still the graph is not displayed. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, reducing the size of the legend (particularly the font size of the labels) is not an option. This is the case, for example, with a one-column figure for a two-column paper.

In your particular case, I would:

1. remove the frame of the legend ;
2. change its position to the top-left side of the figure ;
3. control the limit of the y axis ;
4. change the order of the labels so that the longer label goes to the top ;
5. gives a unique line style to each plot to further differentiate them ;
6. fine-tune the font size of the labels and their vertical spacing in the legend.

Below is an example to show you how this could be done:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

plt.close('all')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.15, 0.80, 0.80])

#---- generate some data ----

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.001)
y1 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 5.2)
y2 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 5)
y3 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 2)

#---- setup ticks ----

ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', top='off', right='off')

#---- set axes labels ----

ax.set_ylabel('Log (frequency)', labelpad=15, fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Image values', labelpad=15, fontsize=14)

#---- plot data ----

h1, = ax.plot(x, y1, color='blue', lw=1.5)
h2, = ax.plot(x, y2, dashes=[2, 3], color='green', lw=2)
h3, = ax.plot(x, y3, dashes=[1.5, 5, 10, 5], color='red', lw=1.5)

#---- plot legend ----

lines = [h1, h2, h3]
labels = ['Transformed input image', 'Reference image', 'Input image']

ax.legend(lines, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), loc='upper left', ncol=1, 
          fontsize=14, labelspacing=0.5, borderaxespad=0.5, frameon=False, 
          handletextpad=1, numpoints=1)

#---- set axis limits ----

ax.axis(ymax=0.22)

#---- show and save ----

plt.show(block=False)
fig.savefig('legend_overlap.png')
```

The code above results in:

[image]

### Update (2015-07-29):

But, if you still want to keep a frame around your legend, you can also play around with the ratio between the width and the height of your figure until the legend fits in the graph. This can be done as shown in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

plt.close('all')

fwidth = 10
fheight = 5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(fwidth, fheight))

left_margin  = 1.1 / fwidth
right_margin = 0.25 / fwidth
bottom_margin = 0.75 / fheight
top_margin = 0.25 / fheight

#---- generate an axe ----

h = 1 - (bottom_margin + top_margin)
w = 1 - (left_margin + right_margin)

ax = fig.add_axes([left_margin, bottom_margin, w, h])

#---- generate some data ----

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.001)
y1 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 5.2)
y2 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 5)
y3 = norm.pdf(x, 0, 2)

#---- setup ticks ----

ax.tick_params(axis='both', direction='out', top='off', right='off')

#---- set axes labels ----

ax.set_ylabel('Log (frequency)', labelpad=15, fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Image values', labelpad=15, fontsize=14)

#---- plot data ----

h1, = ax.plot(x, y1, color='blue', lw=1.5)
h2, = ax.plot(x, y2, dashes=[2, 3], color='green', lw=2)
h3, = ax.plot(x, y3, dashes=[1.5, 5, 10, 5], color='red', lw=1.5)

#---- plot legend ----

lines = [h1, h2, h3]
labels = ['Transformed input image', 'Reference image', 'Input image']

ax.legend(lines, labels, loc='upper right', ncol=1, fancybox=True,
          fontsize=14, labelspacing=0.5, handletextpad=1, numpoints=1)

#---- set axis limits ----

ax.axis(ymax=0.22)

#---- show and save ----

plt.show(block=False)
fig.savefig('legend_overlap_alternate.png')
```

Which results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix it is by adjusting the size as:

```
plt.legend(prop={'size':10},loc='upper right')
```

Moreover, I specify the location of the legend as well. The result is:
[image]

That's a way. If someone has something else to propose, it will be interesting.